# Index of bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bilinear-form

I am faced with the following problem:

Given $\beta$ a bilinear form with determinant less than 0 in $R^6$ such that:

> $\beta(u_1, u_1) > 0$
>
> $\beta(u_2, u_2) < 0$
>
> $\beta(u_4, u_4) > 0$
>
> $\beta(u_5, u_5) < 0$

where $\{u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4, u_5, u_6\}$ is a basis of $R^6$ and that $L_1 = span(\{u_1, u_2, u_3\})$ is orthogonal to $L_2 = span(\{u_4, u_5, u_6\})$ with respect to $\beta$, prove that the index and coindex of $\beta$ are both 3.

I can't understand why this is true. Couldn't the index be 1 and the coindex 5, for example? I have, however, failed at finding a counterexample.

Comment: What are the $L$'s?

Comment: They are subspaces.

Comment: Generated by the vectors enclosed in the curly brackets?

Comment: Yes, exactly, which all joined form a basis of $R^6$. They are complementary subspaces.

Comment: The standard term is "span":
$$
L_{1} = {\tt span \; } \{u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}\}.
$$

Comment: @avs Oh, I knew about the term but that is the notation I always used. Thought It was more or less global, should have clarified it.

Comment: No worries.  One other point: not only is the notation $L_{k}$ not global, it can be confused sometimes with the more-or-less global notation for the Lebesgue spaces.

Comment: @avs Thank you, I have edited it. Could you help me about the answer? A brief sketch of the proof would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is the maximal possible dimension of a negative definite subspace.  Since the form $\beta$ is negative definite on at least the span of $\{u_2,  u_5\}$ (a 2-dimensional subspace), its index cannot be smaller than 2.

Similarly, the co-index cannot be smaller than 2.  Therefore, the index cannot exceed 4.

Why can't the index equal 4?  This, I think, needs to be examined using the negativity of the determinant of $\beta$.

Comment: I can see it now, thank you. And thank you for the notational remarks.